# regexp string matching a single word

Tags: regular-expressions

I am looking to match the word `as` on its own and am using

```
(s-replace-regexp "\\<as\\>" "s" word)
```

Is this the way to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `"\\bas\\b"` in most situations, but YMMV.

Comment: Do you use `\\<` and `\\>`, or do you keep with `\\b` for beginning and end of a word?

Comment: gnu manual supports your use for matching any occurrence of `as` as a separate word.